# Is there any way to take a user keyword as a value in a cell in RIDE?

Tags: robotframework

I want to use the return value of a keyword as an argument of another keyword.
Ex:

```
Should Be Equal   [My Keyword]    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.
You have to go through an intermediate variable assignment:

```
${found} =  [My Keyword]
Should Be Equal  ${found}  3
```

Comment: I have to do the same thing as you've told. So thanks for answer me